# Change text of Bootstrap when clicked Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I want to change the text of my tooltip when it is clicked.
This is my current code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $('.mail').tooltip('hide')
        .attr('data-original-title', "hola")
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
}
```

And the tooltip I want to change is this one

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="mail">
    <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copia mi correo" src="img/mail.png" onclick="myFunction()">
</a>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have added `.attr('data-original-title', "hola").tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');` to `$('.mail')` it need to be in `img` inside `$('.mail')`. Here is an example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'tool tip has been changed.')
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="mail">
    <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copia mi correo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a bit better but it doesnt change when I click, I have unhover and hover again

Comment: Have you checked my example? First click and hover

Comment: Yes I have check and when you click it doesnt change, you have to hover again to see the change.

Comment: This works, but you need to blur and rehover again.
to fix it you can:
`$(this).tooltip('hide'); $(this).tooltip('show');`

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>You can use:</pre>

<a onclick="test()" id="test" href="#" data-toggle="testtip" title="first content!">Click me</a>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="testtip"]').tooltip();   
});
function test() {
$("a").attr("data-original-title", "New content");  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers use the method `tooltip('dispose')`. I'll post my answer anyway because none of the answers answer a live update of the tooltip.

I also immediately provide a working version for Bootstrap 4 & 5

This Bootstrap method and more can be [found here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#tooltipdispose)

**Bootstrap 5:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $('.mail').on('click', function() {
    let el = $(this);
    let d = new Date();
    let cur_time = `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}`;
    el.find('img').attr('data-bs-original-title', `My new text ${cur_time}`).tooltip('dispose').tooltip().tooltip('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
  <a href="#" class="mail">
    <img data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-original-title="my old text" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  
  $('.mail').on('click', function() {
    let el = $(this);
    el.find('img').attr('title', 'My new text').tooltip('dispose').tooltip().tooltip('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
  <a href="#" class="mail">
    <img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="my old text" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code works

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="mail">
<img id="myinput" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Copia mi correo" src="img/mail.png" onclick="myFunction()">
```

javascript code

```
function myFunction()
{   
    document.getElementById("myinput").setAttribute("title", "My new toogle text");


}
```

Comment: Sorry but this do nothing

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery

```
$(this).tooltip('hide')
.attr('data-original-title', 'new text')
.tooltip('show');
```